# CSS container mask with single line ul of varying width

Tags: html, css

Trying to make something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvvCR.png).

So, it's like a jQuery carousel, but not using jQuery, dont want any animation, just simple pagination to move the "visible" section around.

Here's the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <style>
    .container {
      width:480px;
      height:70px;  
      background:#ff0000;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    .container ul {
      list-style-type:none;
      display:block;    
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      width:auto;
    }

    .container ul li {
      float:left;
      display:inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="image.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The current problem is that once the `ul` reaches the width of the .container, it breaks and makes 2 rows.  I need the `ul` to stretch, just be one row, and be masked by the container.

We have an indeterminate amount of images pulled in from a database, so that will always change the width of the `ul`.  The container width and `li` width will always be the same.

I can't figure this out, and I would like to avoid jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: Why are you avoiding Javascript? It does this sort of thing extremely well. You saying "like jQuery carousel but not jQuery" seems a little odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're rendering your page, set the width on the `<ul>` directly using the `style` attribute.  Since the `<li>` width will always be constant, width will be:

```
number of images returned * li width
```

Assuming PHP as your server side language, it would be something like so:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul style="width: <?php echo $count_imgs * CONSTANT_WIDTH ?>px">
      // echo your image <li>'s
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PJqdv/2/) of it working.

If setting the width while rendering the page isn't an option, you could just define an arbitrarily large width on the `<ul>`.  It wouldn't be as nice though since you'd end up with empty space at the end of your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `inline-block`s. When using them you can add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent, so they wouldn't jump on the new line and you could scroll it using, for example, negative margin on the first `li`.

Here I created fiddle for you showing this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/qrmC5/

Also, don't forget about `display:inline;zoom:1;` fix for IE, add this ti your block-lever `inline-block`s in conditional comments.